# Using jquery connections but it isn't connecting div's together?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am trying to create this page where I have different div and buttons that are scattered on the page and connecting them using jquery connections by [musclesoft](https://github.com/musclesoft/jquery-connections/)

I have tried this code but it seems that the connection isn't happening at all, I can't figure out what the issue is?

```css
button {
  min-width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  background: #f56c29;
  border-radius: 60px;
}

connection {
  border: 30px solid #b51c29;
  border-radius: 50px;
}


button.about {
  position: absolute;
  transition: .5s ease;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
<!-- Include jQuery and the Connections plugin -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.connections.js"></script>
<!-- Connect your elements like in this example -->
<script>
  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $('div').connections();
  });
</script>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>CodePen - A Pen by rasbsal</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">

</head>
<body>
  <div>
      <button>
          Text
      </button>
  </div>
  <div>
      <button class="about">
          About
      </button>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you checked the console for errors?

Comment: Yes, no errors at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The connections are not visible because there's actually no space between the `div` elements (go to Inspect Element in Dev Tools and see for yourself highlighting the two DIV elements).
**Use `button` as your *connecting* selector**

```js
jQuery(($) => {
  $('button').connections();
});
```

```css
button {
  min-width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  background: #f56c29;
  border-radius: 60px;
}

connection {
  border: 30px solid #b51c29;
  border-radius: 50px;
}

button.about {
  position: absolute;
  transition: .5s ease;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button>Text</button>
</div>
<div>
  <button class="about">About</button>
</div>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/musclesoft/jquery-connections@1.0.1/jquery.connections.js"></script>
```